# determining ip and port in connection between two client - php

Tags: php, sockets, ip, port

**1-** when we use stream_socket_client() for connect from client A to B. we specify port of B and connect to it and port of A is random. can we specify port of A too ??

**2-** I use this code for accepting incoming connectiongs:

```
$a = stream_socket_server('tcp://localhost:9056');
$b = stream_socket_accept($a);
$c = fread($b,1000);
```

now how detect ip and port of incoming connection ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you can.

   `$opts = array(
       'socket' => array(
           'bindto' => '0:7000',
       ),
   );`

   `$context = stream_context_create($opts);`

   `$fp = stream_socket_client("tcp://localhost:9056", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context );`
2. You can get client socket information using **stream_socket_get_name** function.

   `$a = stream_socket_server('tcp://localhost:9056');
   $b = stream_socket_accept($a);
   $addr = stream_socket_get_name($b,true);
   $c = fread($b,1000);`

Comment: in `0:7000` start port is **7000** but what is **0** ??

Comment: That's IP address. If you have multiple network interfaces on your server, you can specify here which one you'd like to bind the socket to.